# Direction field of light reflected on phone

Tags: optics, everyday-life, diffraction

When looking at my phone, a light from the roof caused my phone to reflect what appears to be a direction (slope) field, that of $y = x$.

Why specifically this pattern?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a picture of your phone without light glaring off it?

Comment: It could easily be due to diagonal scratches on the display cover.

Comment: For clarity, are you talking about the white pattern or the multi-coloured grid?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The multi-coloured grid

Comment: @S.McGrew. Nope.

Comment: @user47014 And nope. My phone is not in any way scratched. I've tried this with different phones (yes, I've actually asked and shown people this effect with their phones - so I'm not crazy).

Comment: @Jossie Calderon Do you have a picture of the light you are referring to?

Comment: Are you talking about the pattern picked up by the camera used to capture the image you posted, or the pattern you see with your eye?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking at is the [diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction) pattern produced by the two-dimensional [diffraction grating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_grating) formed by the pixels in the screen.

Each diffraction grating will produce a square array of points at each wavelength of light, so if you focus only on (say) the red dots, you will see that they form a square array, with each dot representing a different order of diffraction.

However, a standard feature of diffraction is that the angles at which the light is diffracted depends (essentially) linearly on the light's wavelength. Thus, the patterns produced by the red, green and blue components of the white-light illumination you are using appear at square grids of different angular spacings. This is what causes the 'streaks' that radiate away from the central observation point in an apparently-linear fashion.

Comment: But why a square array and not a circular array?

Comment: @JossieCalderon Because the diffraction grating is a square array itself.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty What is making that happen in this case? Try to get the same results with a phone reflecting light in other cases. I don't see it. My only guess is that this light is really bright, thus one can see the diffraction where normally they wouldn't.

Comment: @Jossie Calderon Is this light really bright?

Comment: @user47014 I tried it the next day and it wasn't there, or it was but almost not visible. Try playing with different angles/lighting.